# IDTR limit is more than 256

Tags: windows-7, x86, x86-64, kernel

I have been doing some hacking for windows and came across a fact when I did SIDT. When I read SIDT, I found that value of IDT limit is 0xFFF(u4096).

I was pretty surprised to find it out. I was under the impression that maximum number of descriptors are 256. Then how come IDTR limit is 0xFFF?

My system is I7 running Win 7 in 64 bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two facts:

- The limit is the highest legal address in the table, not the highest interrupt number.
- An IDT entry takes up 8 bytes in x86-32.  In x86-64, it doubles (to 16 bytes) in order to handle the larger addresses.

256 * 16 = 4096.  Bytes would start at offset 0 and end at 4095.

(BTW, 0xFFF is equal to 4095, not 4096.)